# How do I not delete files in only the directory I am in?

Tags: files, date, rm, delete

I want to delete files older than 30 days in a directory, but not in directories below the one I am in.

Comment: What do you mean by `below`? Are you talking about subdirectories or directories listed below when you list in a sorted-by-time order?

Comment: I saw the "not delete" in the title after answering your question. Is it correct that you want to delete files in the current directory, but not in subdirectories?

Answer (score 2):

To list the files before you delete them:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mtime +30 -type f -ls
```

To delete the files:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mtime +30 -type f -exec rm {} +
```

with

- `.` specifying the current directory
- `-maxdepth 1` descend at most 1 level of directories
- `-mtime +30` only files last modified > 30 days
- `-type f` only regular files

Comment: Should it be `+29` ? I think `+0` is  1 day ago ?

Comment: @dedowsdi Yes, you are right, but the question says "older than 30 days", so `+30` is correct, i.e. it's 31 days ago and more.

Comment: In the `find` man page for option `-atime` it says "_-atime +1, a file has to have been accessed at least two days ago_", 
so `-mtime +30` means at least 31 days. I guess it depends on the interpretation of "older than x days".

Answer (score 0):

The zsh shell has [special wildcard expansion features](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zshexpn) that would help.

- list files older than 30 days in the current directory: `ls -d -- *(.m+30)`
- remove files older than 30 days in the current directory: `rm -- *(.m+30)`

The zsh syntax of `*(.m+30)` is a wildcard that means:

- `*` -- any filename
- `( ... )` -- with a qualifier of...
- `.` -- a regular file (not a directory, etc)
- `m+30` -- the modification time is greater than 30 days ago